# How to add to array by id in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I'm trying to update an existing array in react using useState, a react hook. What I'm doing in the function below is trying to update the array by id. I want to update the inner 'inspections' array and add a new inspection. But whats happening instead is that it's adding to the end of the 'data' array and not to the end of 'inspections' array.

Here is my array:

```
export const data = [
  {
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999),
    description: "",
    type: "car",
    inspections: [
      {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999),
        name: `Inspection${Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)}`,
        type: "any",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Here is my update function:

```
 const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState(data);
 const [inspection, setInspection] = useState("");

 function handleInspection(id) {
    setDataArray((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        id: id,
        description: "",
        type: "",
        inspections: [
          {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999),
            name: `Inspection${Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)}`,
            type: inspection,
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);
  }
```

Here is the data mapped and radio buttons, I'm using radio buttons to select what kind of inspection you can choose: any, car, lorry, van. Once you select an Inspection you should be able to click the button and 'add a new inspection' to an existing array of inspections.

```
  {dataArray.map((vehicles) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div key={vehicles.id}>vehicle type:{vehicles.type}</div>
              <ul>
                {vehicles.inspections.map((inspection) => {
                  return <li>type: {inspection.type}</li>;
                })}
                lorry
                <input
                  name="option"
                  type="radio"
                  className="form-control"
                  autoFocus={true}
                  onChange={() => setInspection("Lorry")}
                  aria-label="Enter the title of your todo"
                  placeholder="Enter a new todo"
                  value={inspection}
                />
                van
                <input
                  name="option"
                  type="radio"
                  className="form-control"
                  onChange={() => setInspection("Van")}
                  autoFocus={true}
                  aria-label="Enter the title of your todo"
                  placeholder="Enter a new todo"
                  value={inspection}
                />
                car
                <input
                  name="option"
                  type="radio"
                  className="form-control"
                  onChange={() => setInspection("Car")}
                  autoFocus={true}
                  aria-label="Enter the title of your todo"
                  placeholder="Enter a new todo"
                  value={inspection}
                />
                any
                <input
                  name="option"
                  type="radio"
                  className="form-control"
                  onChange={() => setInspection("Any")}
                  autoFocus={true}
                  aria-label="Enter the title of your todo"
                  placeholder="Enter a new todo"
                  value={inspection}
                />
              </ul>
              <button
                className="addButton"
                onClick={() => handleInspection(vehicles.id)}
              >
                Add Inspection
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the index of the array element where you want to add inspection
   using **findIndex** method (based on id)
2. update data based in Index value
3. add new object in **inspections**

your *handleInspection* function would be like this if you want to add new inspection in that particular data **id**

```
function handleInspection(id) {
  setDataArray((prevState) => {

    //find Index of given ID

    const elementIndex = prevState.findIndex((ele) => ele.id == id); 
     
    // updating data at that particular Index
    prevState[elementIndex] = {
    
    ...prevState[elementIndex],
    inspections: [
      ...prevState[elementIndex].inspections,
     //adding new inspection in that particular ID
     {
        id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999),
        name: `Inspection${Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999)}`,
        type: inspection,
      },
     ],
   };
   return prevState; // return the updated data
 });
}
```